# Reuse a view as a modal and non-modal (angularjs + bootstrap-ui)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I currently use `views/foo.html` as a normal view.

Say this view has this:

```
  <p>Hello</p>
```

Now I want to reuse `views/foo.html` as the content of a modal, **but I'd like to wrap it with this:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Foo</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
     <!-- I want to include views/foo.html in here -->
</div>
```

So the modal would look like this:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Foo</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
     <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

The modal invoker is the following: (notice the comment)

```
$scope.openFooModal = function () {

    var modalScope = $scope.$new();

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/foo.html', /* HERE I NEED TO WRAP IT */
        controller: 'fooController',
        scope: modalScope,
        size: 'lg'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    }, null);
};
```

What is the best solution?
Should I create a foo2.html ?

Comment: Use ngInclude (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), or make a directive out of your shared html template, and use the directive in your main page template and in your modal template.

Comment: It worked. Post it as an answer if you want me to accept it as an answer. `<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">My Modal</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><ng-include src="'views/foo.html'"></ng-include></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end the comment made by JB Nizet worked as a start, but there was this issue:
[Inject $uibModalInstance to a controllar not initiated by a $uibModal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767680/inject-uibmodalinstance-to-a-controllar-not-initiated-by-a-uibmodal/37768522)

This is what I did finally:

view in charge of opening the modal or displaying it as an ng-view:

```
  <body ng-controller="indexController">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" ng-click="openModal()">Open as modal</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nonmodal">Open as non modal</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view=""></div> <!-- Used by routeProvider -->
  </body>
```

...its controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('indexController', ['$scope','$uibModal', function($scope,$uibModal) {

    $scope.openModal = function () {

        var modalScope = $scope.$new();

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'foo-as-modal.html',
            controller: 'fooController',
            scope: modalScope
        });

        modalScope.modalInstance = modalInstance;
             // ^ I'm giving the modal his own reference
             //   using the scope. Injecting wont work on
             //   the non-modal case!

        modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        }, null);
    };
}]);
```

view to be reused as a modal or as a non-modal:

```
<p>Hello {{name}}</p>
```

its controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('fooController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
                                                     // ^ 
                                                     // I'm not injecting
                                                     // uibModalInstance
                                                     // (this is important)


    $scope.name = "John";

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          // ^ I can access the modalInstance by the $scope
    };
}]);
```

view to be used as a modal (wrapper)

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-include src="'foo.html'"></ng-include> <!-- Credits to JB's comment -->
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
</div>
```

routeProvider

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/nonmodal', {
        templateUrl: 'foo.html',
        controller: 'fooController'
    })
```

Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZasHQhl6M5cCc9yaZTd5?p=info